# Bad positioning in tree

Tags: tikz-trees, trees, forest, automata

I wanted to use `forest` to build a tree, but I need each node to be the same layout as when using `state` from `\usetikzlibrary{automata}`, so I had to create the tree with the normal nodes in tikz.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    node distance=0.8cm,
    ->,
    every node/.style = {state}
]
\node {$s_1$}
    child {
        node {$s_2$}
            child {
                node {$s_3$}
                    child {
                        node {$s_4$}
                    }
            }
            child {
                node {$s_5$}
                    child {
                        node {$s_6$}
                    }
                    child {
                        node {$s_7$}
                    }
            }
    }
    child {
        node {$s_8$}
            child {
                node {$s_9$}
                    child {
                        node {$s_{10}$}
                    }
            }
            child {
                node {$s_{11}$}
            }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but it turns out the tree is not balanced at all (the positions are very bad):

[image]

Can I either fix the positions or do the exact same in `forest` with same node and path/arrow style as now?

I have the same tree with `forest`:

```
\begin{forest}
[$s_1$
    [$s_2$
        [$s_3$
            [$s_4$]
            [,phantom]
        ]
        [$s_5$
            [$s_6$]
            [$s_7$]
        ]
    ]
    [$s_8$
        [$s_9$
            [,phantom]
            [$s_{10}$]
        ]
        [$s_{11}$]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
```

but it has a very different styling:

[image]

Is it possible to add something like

```
for tree={state},
for path={normal path}
```

Comment: Could you please make your code into a compilable example? The Forest code you posted won't produce the output you show it as giving.

Comment: Try playing with `level 2/.style={sibling distance=10mm}` and friends. also works for other levels. Proper node positioning may take a while...

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Or use Forest ;).

Comment: You've edited to remove the line which caused your code (when minimally completed) to produce output much more like that you want, so now it probably does produce the output shown although it is hard to tell as you have still not provided a compilable version, just one which is probably less like the image you say you want to create. Confused .... Do you not want the circles around the nodes? Why not make the code examples compilable so it is easier for everyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted does not produce the output shown for the Forest tree. I'm not familiar with `automata` and have no idea how `normal path` is defined or what defines it, so I just use `->` here instead.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    math content,
    state,
    edge={->},
  }
  [s_1
      [s_2
          [s_3
              [s_4]
              [,phantom]
          ]
          [s_5
              [s_6]
              [s_7]
          ]
      ]
      [s_8
          [s_9
              [,phantom]
              [s_{10}]
          ]
          [s_{11}]
      ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: customised tree]